# How can i make my Firebase Database read only the immediate children of a given reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner coder, and i'm working on a project in Android Studio, using firebase. I structured my DB to save males in one directory and females in another (users) so as to ease the later features of the app. 
The basic structure is below

[The picture of my database layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4O8E.png)

At some point in my code, i want to check whether a certain user is Male or female, and this is the code i am using to do so. However, it is giving me undesired results. Its saying thr user is both male and female.

code is below:

```
  DatabaseReference mUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

This is the reference to my users.

```
  mUsers.child("Male").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(userId)){
                        gender = "Male";
                        Log.i("The_current's_gender", gender);
                        mUsers.child(gender).child(userId).child("connections").child("nope").child(currentUserId).setValue(true);
                    }else{
                        gender = "Female";
                        Log.i("The_current's_gender", gender);
                        mUsers.child(gender).child(userId).child("connections").child("nope").child(currentUserId).setValue(true);
                    }
                }
```

And this is the snippet of the troublesome part.

This is running properly with no errors, however, I'm receiving log information that says my User is both male and female. How can i structure my event listener to give me the person's gender? I have attempted to look up documentation on the listeners but nothing is helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a structure like this in your database:

```
Male: {
  "uidOfMaleOne": ...,
  "uidOfMaleTwo": ...
}
```

When you attach a `ChildEventListener` to `Male` its `onChildAdded` gets called with each child node in turn. Say that we're `uidOfMaleOne`, then on the first call to `onChildAdded`, the `dataSnapshot.getKey()` matches our UID, so we set `gender = "Male"`. But then on the second call to `onChildAdded`, the `dataSnapshot.getKey()` does **not** match our UID and we set `gender = "Female"`.

You'll probably want to only load a single node in this structure: the one of the current user. Something like:

```
mUsers.child("Male").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            gender = "Male";
            Log.i("The_current's_gender", gender);
            mUsers.child(gender).child(userId).child("connections").child("nope").child(currentUserId).setValue(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr @frank.. In your code. If there was a child somewhere in the male folder that has the user ID In it. Saaayy.. A child containing profiles for all the profiles that a given Male user has viewed (including the user ID). Wouldn't that child be captured by the data snapshot and as such, give a gender result of Male automatically... For literally every profile that said male user has viewed.

Comment: It has worked excellently.  Exactly as it's supposed to. Thank you so much. My question up there is still pending though.